# How old is too old to rehome a genet kitten?

Tags: behavior, multi-pet-families, introducing-pets, genet

I've been researching genets (particularly common and Angolan) as pets. From my understanding once they bond they bond for life and are highly intolerant to home/owner changes. I've also heard that they will get along fine with larger animals (e.g. cats and dogs; anything smaller is a snack) as long as they are raised around those animals.

Now, when looking for kittens, there are various ages, from newborn up to 7 or 8 months (the oldest I've seen).

My question is, when do their bonds primarily form? How old would be considered too old to bring a genet kitten into my home?

Comment: Where are you from? Are you sure genets are legal as pets there?

Comment: @SerenaT In my state, it is possible to own them as long as I can obtain a permit and have the animal fixed. Most of research effort I have to put in to get a permit regards enclosures.

Comment: So I feel like I searched the whole internet now, the only thing I could find is that genet kittens are fully developed at 18 weeks. https://www.zuriorphanage.com/namibian-animals/genet/ . I recommend you find someone or a community that is familiar with keeping genets. They will know more.